# sphinx3 decode error after perl scripts_pl/decode/slave.pl

Tags: speech-recognition

After installing sphinx3 and trying to decode

using these commands

perl scripts/setup_tutorial.pl my data

I had this error

Aligning results to find error rate
word_align.pl failed with error code 6400 at scripts_pl/decode/slave.pl line 173

these are

word_align.pl and slave.pl

1-word_align.pl

```js
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

# word_align.pl - Calculate word error and accuracy for a recognition
# hypothesis file vs. a reference transcription
#
# Written by David Huggins-Daines <dhuggins@cs.cmu.edu> for Speech
# Recognition and Understanding 11-751, Carnegie Mellon University,
# October 2004.

use strict;
use Getopt::Long;
use Pod::Usage;
use vars qw($Verbose $CER $IgnoreUttID);
use encoding 'utf8';

my ($help,%hyphash);
GetOptions(
    'help|?' => \$help,
    'verbose|v' => \$Verbose,
    'cer|c' => \$CER,
    'ignore-uttid|i' => \$IgnoreUttID,
   ) or pod2usage(1);
pod2usage(1) if $help;

pod2usage(2) unless @ARGV == 2;
my ($ref, $hyp) = @ARGV;

open HYP, "<$hyp" or die "Failed to open $hyp: $!";
while (defined(my $hyp_utt=<HYP>)){
    my $hyp_uttid;
    ($hyp_utt, $hyp_uttid) = s3_magic_norm($hyp_utt);
    $hyphash{$hyp_uttid} = "$hyp_utt ($hyp_uttid)";
}
close HYP;

open REF, "<$ref" or die "Failed to open $ref: $!";
open HYP, "<$hyp" or die "Failed to open $hyp: $!";

use constant INS => 1;
use constant DEL => 2;
use constant MATCH => 3;
use constant SUBST => 4;
use constant BIG_NUMBER => 1e50;

my ($total_words, $total_match, $total_cost);
my ($total_ins, $total_del, $total_subst);
while (defined(my $ref_utt = <REF>)) {
    my $hyp_utt;
    my $ref_uttid;
    my $hyp_uttid;

    ($ref_utt,$ref_uttid)=s3_magic_norm($ref_utt);

    last if ($ref_utt =~ /^\s*$/);

    if(defined $IgnoreUttID){
 $hyp_utt = <HYP>;
 die "UttID is ignored but file size mismatch between $ref and $hyp" unless defined($hyp_utt);
    }else{
 $hyp_utt=$hyphash{$ref_uttid};
        die "UttID is not ignored but it could not found in any entries of the hypothesis file on line3 $. UTTID: $ref_uttid\n" unless defined($hyp_utt);
    }

    ($hyp_utt,$hyp_uttid)=s3_magic_norm($hyp_utt);

    if(! defined $IgnoreUttID){
 die "Utterance ID mismatch on line $.: $ref_uttid != $hyp_uttid"
     unless $ref_uttid eq $hyp_uttid;
    }

    # Split the text into an array of words
    my @ref_words = split ' ', $ref_utt;
    my @hyp_words = split ' ', $hyp_utt;
    if ($CER) {
 # Split the text into an array of characters
 @ref_words = map { split "" } @ref_words;
 @hyp_words = map { split "" } @hyp_words;
    }

    my (@align_matrix, @backtrace_matrix);

    # Initialize the alignment and backtrace matrices
    initialize(\@ref_words, \@hyp_words, \@align_matrix, \@backtrace_matrix);
    # Do DP alignment maintaining backtrace pointers
    my $cost = align(\@ref_words, \@hyp_words, \@align_matrix, \@backtrace_matrix);
    # Find the backtrace
    my ($alignment, $ins, $del, $subst, $match) = backtrace(\@ref_words, \@hyp_words,
           \@align_matrix, \@backtrace_matrix);

    # Format the alignment nicely
    my ($ref_align, $hyp_align) = ("", "");
    foreach (@$alignment) {
 my ($ref, $hyp) = @$_;
 my $width = 0;

 if ($CER) {
     # Assume this is Chinese, no capitalization so put ** around errors
     if (defined($ref) and defined($hyp) and $ref ne $hyp) {
  $ref = "*$ref*";
  $hyp = "*$hyp*";
     }
 }
 else {
     # Capitalize errors (they already are...), lowercase matches
     if (defined($ref) and defined($hyp) and $ref eq $hyp) {
  $ref = lc $ref;
  $hyp = lc $hyp;
     }
 }

 # Replace deletions with ***
 foreach ($ref, $hyp) { $_ = "***" unless defined $_ };

 # Find the width of this column
 foreach ($ref, $hyp) { $width = length if length > $width };
 $width = 3 if $width < 3; # Make it long enough for ***

 # Space out the words and concatenate them to the output
 $ref_align .= sprintf("%-*s ", $width, $ref);
 $hyp_align .= sprintf("%-*s ", $width, $hyp);
    }
    print "$ref_align ($ref_uttid)\n$hyp_align ($hyp_uttid)\n";

    # Print out the word error and accuracy rates
    my $error = @ref_words == 0 ? 1 : $cost/@ref_words;
    my $acc = @ref_words == 0 ? 0 : $match/@ref_words;
    printf("Words: %d Correct: %d Errors: %d Percent correct = %.2f%% Error = %.2f%% Accuracy = %.2f%%\n",
    scalar(@ref_words), $match, $cost, $acc*100, $error*100, 100-$error*100);
    print "Insertions: $ins Deletions: $del Substitutions: $subst\n";

    $total_cost += $cost;
    $total_match += $match;
    $total_words += @ref_words;
    $total_ins += $ins;
    $total_del += $del;
    $total_subst += $subst;
}
# Print out the total word error and accuracy rates
my $error = $total_cost/$total_words;
my $acc = $total_match/$total_words;
printf("TOTAL Words: %d Correct: %d Errors: %d\nTOTAL Percent correct = %.2f%% Error = %.2f%% Accuracy = %.2f%%\n",
       $total_words, $total_match, $total_cost, $acc*100, $error*100, 100-$error*100);
print "TOTAL Insertions: $total_ins Deletions: $total_del Substitutions: $total_subst\n";

# This function normalizes a line of a match file. 
sub s3_magic_norm{
    my ($word)=@_;

    # Remove line endings
    chomp  $word;
    # Normalize case
    $word = uc $word;   
    # Remove filler words and context cues
    $word =~ s/<[^>]+>//g;
    $word =~ s/\+\+[^+]+\+\+//g;
    $word =~ s/\+[^+]+\+//g;

    # Remove alternative pronunciations
    $word =~ s/\([1-9]\)//g;

    # Remove class tags
    $word =~ s/:\S+//g;

    # This compute the uttid and remove it from a line.
    $word =~ s/\(([^) ]+)[^)]*\)$// ;

    # Split apart compound words and acronyms
    $word =~ tr/-_./  /;

    return ($word,$1);
}

sub initialize {
    my ($ref_words, $hyp_words, $align_matrix, $backtrace_matrix) = @_;

    # All initial costs along the j axis are insertions
    for (my $j = 0; $j <= @$hyp_words; ++$j) {
 $$align_matrix[0][$j] = $j;
    }
    for (my $j = 0; $j <= @$hyp_words; ++$j) {
 $$backtrace_matrix[0][$j] = INS;
    }
    # All initial costs along the i axis are deletions
    for (my $i = 0; $i <= @$ref_words; ++$i) {
 $$align_matrix[$i][0] = $i;
    }
    for (my $i = 0; $i <= @$ref_words; ++$i) {
 $$backtrace_matrix[$i][0] = DEL;
    }
}

sub align {
    my ($ref_words, $hyp_words, $align_matrix, $backtrace_matrix) = @_;

    for (my $i = 1; $i <= @$ref_words; ++$i) {
 for (my $j = 1; $j <= @$hyp_words; ++$j) {
     # Find insertion, deletion, substitution scores
     my ($ins, $del, $subst);

     # Cost of a substitution (0 if they are equal)
     my $cost = $$ref_words[$i-1] ne $$hyp_words[$j-1];

     # Find insertion, deletion, substitution costs
     $ins = $$align_matrix[$i][$j-1] + 1;
     $del = $$align_matrix[$i-1][$j] + 1;
     $subst = $$align_matrix[$i-1][$j-1] + $cost;
     print "Costs at $i $j: INS $ins DEL $del SUBST $subst\n" if $Verbose;

     # Get the minimum one
     my $min = BIG_NUMBER;
     foreach ($ins, $del, $subst) {
  if ($_ < $min) {
      $min = $_;
  }
     }
     $$align_matrix[$i][$j] = $min;

     # If the costs are equal, prefer match or substitution
     # (keep the path diagonal).
     if ($min == $subst) {
  print(($cost ? "SUBSTITUTION" : "MATCH"),
        "($$ref_words[$i-1] <=> $$hyp_words[$j-1])\n") if $Verbose;
  $$backtrace_matrix[$i][$j] = MATCH+$cost;
     }
     elsif ($min == $ins) {
  print "INSERTION (0 => $$hyp_words[$j-1])\n" if $Verbose;
  $$backtrace_matrix[$i][$j] = INS;
     }
     elsif ($min == $del) {
  print "DELETION ($$ref_words[$i-1] => 0)\n" if $Verbose;
  $$backtrace_matrix[$i][$j] = DEL;
     }
 }
    }
    return $$align_matrix[@$ref_words][@$hyp_words];
}

sub backtrace {
    my ($ref_words, $hyp_words, $align_matrix, $backtrace_matrix) = @_;

    # Backtrace to find number of ins/del/subst
    my @alignment;
    my $i = @$ref_words;
    my $j = @$hyp_words;
    my ($inspen, $delpen, $substpen, $match) = (0,0,0,0);
    while (!($i == 0 and $j == 0)) {
 my $pointer = $$backtrace_matrix[$i][$j];
 print "Cost at $i $j: $$align_matrix[$i][$j]\n"
     if $Verbose;
 if ($pointer == INS) {
     print "INSERTION (0 => $$hyp_words[$j-1])" if $Verbose;
     # Append the pair 0:hyp[j] to the front of the alignment
     unshift @alignment, [undef, $$hyp_words[$j-1]];
     ++$inspen;
     --$j;
     print " - moving to $i $j\n" if $Verbose;
 }
 elsif ($pointer == DEL) {
     print "DELETION ($$ref_words[$i-1] => 0)" if $Verbose;
     # Append the pair ref[i]:0 to the front of the alignment
     unshift @alignment, [$$ref_words[$i-1], undef];
     ++$delpen;
     --$i;
     print " - moving to $i $j\n" if $Verbose;
 }
 elsif ($pointer == MATCH) {
     print "MATCH ($$ref_words[$i-1] <=> $$hyp_words[$j-1])" if $Verbose;
     # Append the pair ref[i]:hyp[j] to the front of the alignment
     unshift @alignment, [$$ref_words[$i-1], $$hyp_words[$j-1]];
     ++$match;
     --$j;
     --$i;
     print " - moving to $i $j\n" if $Verbose;
 }
 elsif ($pointer == SUBST) {
     print "SUBSTITUTION ($$ref_words[$i-1] <=> $$hyp_words[$j-1])" if $Verbose;
     # Append the pair ref[i]:hyp[j] to the front of the alignment
     unshift @alignment, [$$ref_words[$i-1], $$hyp_words[$j-1]];
     ++$substpen;
     --$j;
     --$i;
     print " - moving to $i $j\n" if $Verbose;
 }
 else {
     last;
 }
    }

    return (\@alignment, $inspen, $delpen, $substpen, $match);
}

__END__

=head1 NAME

calculate_wer - Calculate Word Error Rate from a reference and hypothesis file

=head1 SYNOPSIS

 calculate_wer [options] reference_file hypothesis_file

=head1 OPTIONS

=over 8

=item B<--help>, B<-?>

Print a brief help message and exit.

=item B<--verbose>, B<-v>

Print out messages tracing the alignment algorithm.

=cut
```

2-slave.pl

```js
#!/usr/bin/perl
# ====================================================================
# Copyright (c) 2000 Carnegie Mellon University.  All rights reserved.
#
# Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
# modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
# are met:
#
# 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
#    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer. 
#
# 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
#    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
#    the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
#    distribution.
#
# This work was supported in part by funding from the Defense Advanced 
# Research Projects Agency and the National Science Foundation of the 
# United States of America, and the CMU Sphinx Speech Consortium.
#
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY CARNEGIE MELLON UNIVERSITY ``AS IS'' AND 
# ANY EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, 
# THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
# PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL CARNEGIE MELLON UNIVERSITY
# NOR ITS EMPLOYEES BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
# SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT 
# LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, 
# DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY 
# THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT 
# (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE 
# OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
#
# ====================================================================
#
#  Script that launches the main decoder script
#
# ====================================================================

use File::Copy;
use File::Basename;
use File::Spec::Functions;

use lib catdir(dirname($0), updir(), 'lib');
use SphinxTrain::Config cfg => 'etc/sphinx_decode.cfg';
use SphinxTrain::Util;

#************************************************************************
# this script launches the decoder scripts.
#************************************************************************

$| = 1; # Turn on autoflushing

if ($ARGV[0] ne '-alignonly') {
    my @jobs;
    Log ("MODULE: DECODE Decoding using models previously trained\n");
    for (my $i = 1; $i <= $ST::DEC_CFG_NPART; $i++) {
 push @jobs, LaunchScript('decode', [$ST::DEC_CFG_SCRIPT,  $i, $ST::DEC_CFG_NPART]);
    }
    foreach my $job (@jobs) {
 WaitForScript($job);
    }
}

Log ("        Aligning results to find error rate\n");
compute_acc();

sub compute_acc {
  $result_dir = "$ST::DEC_CFG_RESULT_DIR";
  $match_file = "$result_dir/${ST::DEC_CFG_EXPTNAME}.match";

  concat_hyp($match_file);
  $tmp_hyp = condition_text($match_file);
  $tmp_ref = condition_text($ST::DEC_CFG_TRANSCRIPTFILE);
  align_hyp($tmp_ref, $tmp_hyp);
  unlink $tmp_ref, $tmp_hyp;
}

sub concat_hyp {
  my $match_file = shift;
  open (MATCH, ">$match_file") or die "Can't open file $match_file\n";
  for (my $i = 1; $i <= $ST::DEC_CFG_NPART; $i++) {

    $hypfile = "$result_dir/${ST::DEC_CFG_EXPTNAME}-${i}-${ST::DEC_CFG_NPART}.match";

    open (HYP, "< $hypfile") or ((warn "Can't open $hypfile\n" and next));
    while (<HYP>) {
 # Remove the acoustic score if any
 s/\((\S+)\s+[^\)]+\)$/($1)/;
 # Remove file paths as they make sclite upset
 s,\(.*/,\(,;
 print MATCH "$_";
    }
    close(HYP);
  }
  close(MATCH);
}

sub condition_text {
  my $fn = shift;
  my $tmpfn = $fn.$$;
  my $fileid = $ST::DEC_CFG_LISTOFFILES;

  open (IN, "< $fn") or die "Can't open $fn for reading\n";
  open (OUT, "> $tmpfn") or die "Can't open $tmpfn for writing\n";
  open (LIST, "< $fileid") or die "Can't open $fileid for reading\n";

  while (<IN>) {
    m/^(.*)\((\S+)\)\s*$/;
# Make them uppercase
    my $text = uc($1);
    my $id = uc($2);
# Removing leading spaces
    $text =~ s/^\s+//;
# Removing trailing spaces
    $text =~ s/\s+$//;
# Removing double spaces;
    $text =~ s/\s+/ /g;
# Removing some unwanted strings
    $text =~ s/_/ /g;
    $text =~ s/\./ /g;
    $text =~ s/\+\+[^\s\+]+\+\+/ /g;
    $text =~ s/\+\+[^\s\+]+\+\+/ /g;
    $text =~ s/<\/?s>/ /gi;
    $text =~ s/<sil>/ /gi;
    $text =~ s/\(\d+\)\b/ /g;
    my $file = <LIST>;
    @path = split /[\\\/]/, $file;
    my $user;
    if ($#path > 0) {
      $user = $path[$#path - 1];
    } else {
      $user = "user";
    }
    print OUT "$text ($user-$id)\n";
  }
  close(LIST);
  close(OUT);
  close(IN);
  return $tmpfn;
}

sub align_hyp {
  my $ref = shift;
  my $hyp = shift;
  my $align = $ST::DEC_CFG_ALIGN;
  my $use_cer = $ST::DEC_CFG_ALIGN_CER eq "yes" ? "--cer" : "";

  if ($align eq 'builtin') {
    my $outfile = "$ST::DEC_CFG_RESULT_DIR/${ST::DEC_CFG_EXPTNAME}.align";
    my $thisdir = dirname($0);
    my ($wer, $ser, $word_total, $sent_total, $sent_err);
    open (OUT, "> $outfile") or die "Can't open $outfile for writing\n";
    my $cmdln = "perl \"$thisdir/word_align.pl\" $use_cer -i \"$ref\" \"$hyp\"";
    $sent_total = 0;
    if (open (PIPE, "$cmdln 2>&1 |")) {
      while (<PIPE>) {
 print OUT "$_";
 if (/^TOTAL Words: (\d+)/) {
     $word_total = $1;
 }
 elsif (/^TOTAL Percent.*Error = ([\d\.]+)%/) {
     $wer = $1;
 }
 elsif (/^Words: (\d+).*Errors: (\d+)/) {
     $sent_total++;
     $sent_err++ if $2;
 }
      }
    }
    close(OUT);
    close(PIPE);
    if ($?) {
 die "word_align.pl failed with error code $?";
    }
    $ser = ($sent_err / $sent_total) * 100;
    Log(sprintf("SENTENCE ERROR: %.1f%% (%d/%d)   %s ERROR RATE: %.1f%% (%d/%d)",
  $ser, $sent_err, $sent_total,
  $use_cer ? "CHARACTER" : "WORD",
  $wer, $word_total * $wer / 100, $word_total), 'result');
    HTML_Print("<p class='result'>", FormatURL("$outfile", "Log File"), "</p>");
  } elsif ($align =~ m/sclite/i) {
    my $outfile = "$ST::DEC_CFG_RESULT_DIR/${ST::DEC_CFG_EXPTNAME}.align";
    my ($wer, $ser, $word_total, $sent_total);
    open (OUT, "> $outfile") or die "Can't open $outfile for writing\n";
    my $cmdln = "\"$align\" " .
   "-i rm " .
   "-o sum pralign dtl stdout " .
   "-f 0 " .
   "-r \"$ref\" " .
   "-h \"$hyp\"";
    if (open (PIPE, "$cmdln 2>&1 |")) {
      while (<PIPE>) {
 print OUT "$_";
 if (m/\|\s*Sum\/Avg\s*\|\s*(\d+)\s*(\d+).*\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s*\|/) {
     $sent_total = $1;
     $word_total = $2;
     $wer = $3;
     $ser = $4;
 }
      }
    }
    close(OUT);
    close(PIPE);
    if ($?) {
 die "sclite failed with error code $?";
    }
    Log(sprintf("SENTENCE ERROR: %.1f%% (%d/%d)   WORD ERROR RATE: %.1f%% (%d/%d)",
  $ser, $sent_total * $ser / 100, $sent_total,
  $wer, $word_total * $wer / 100, $word_total), 'result');
    HTML_Print("<p class='result'>", FormatURL("$outfile", "Log File"), "</p>");
  } else {
    Log("Accuracy not computed, please visually compare the decoder output with the reference file");
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It's not helpful to post your entire code.  Try debugging the error and find out what's going on then ask a question based on that problem.